# How to access selectedItems of a ListBox from ShellViewModel.cs file?

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

**So here is my problem:**

I want to access the items (and their properties), which are bound to a ListBox via a Bindable Collection, in a method of another class. (ShellViewModel) 
More precise: I want to know which Items in this List are currently selected.

I'm using **C#,Caliburn.Micro and the design pattern should be MVVM**.

If the Button "Evaluate" is pressed, according to the selected ListBoxItems, different Methods get called.

So the XAML-Code in the ShellView is working fine, and also the "functional" code "works", but it is just working if I code directly in the xaml.cs-file. (big no,no)

Because I'm quite new to this topics, I've tried to create a new instance of the View for the access, but this will just give me control over the ListBox without "knowing" which Items are selected in the original instance.

Here is the general ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SCollection}" 
           Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="1" 
           SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                 MaxHeight="300" MinHeight="200" MaxWidth="340" Margin="5">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="0,5">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3,5,5,5" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Info}" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="3,5,5,5" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```
<Button x:Name="Evaluate" Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" MinWidth="80" Margin="5" Content="Test" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
```

***So here are some questions:***

*Is there a similar solution like the binding of "SelectedItem" via xaml, which is bound to accessible variable, for multiple selected Items?(maybe I just missed something there?)*

*Is there a way to access the "original" instance of the ListBox(and therefore "live"-selected Items)?*

**To be clear:
Only problem, besides maybe other better solutions out there, is that, I want the called Method "Evaluate", which is bound to the button, have access to the great knowledge of which Items are selected in my ListBox.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I understood your concern correctly. For the Evaluate method to have the knowledge of which Items has been selected, you can adopt the following strategy.

Add a **boolean** property in your Collection Type called **IsSelected**, which would help in tracking the items which are selected. For example,

```
public class Contact : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Now assuming your Collection is defined as following.

public ObservableCollection SCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection();

You can filter the Selected items in Evaluate Method as following.

```
public void Evaluate()
{
    var selected = SCollection.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
}
```

**Update**

You would need to Set the IsSelected Property to true during the selection in the List box. This can be done as following.

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SCollection}" 
                 SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                 MaxHeight="300" MinHeight="200" MaxWidth="340" Margin="5">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="0,5">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3,5,5,5" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Info}" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="3,5,5,5" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

Example Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great input. I tried this but im getting var selected as empty..so I dont know, maybe I'm doing something wrong with the IsSelected property? Is there something,which might be obvious, but isn't stated in your comment? (is the BindableCollection also able to do this actions, same as the observable?)

Comment: @Juretschko I have updated the Answer to reflect how to update the IsSelected property when changing Selection in the ListView. I should have included that in the answer in first place, my mistake. Please do let me know if it resolves your issue

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working fine with the xaml update!

Comment: @Juretschko Glad to help yu